# swift - creating a String from an Object array

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have an array of objects.

*representing it as a JSON array to easily understand the object array*

```
[
  {
    id:343,
    name:"John"
  },
  {
    id:342,
    name:"Doe"
  }
]
```

I need to create a String concatenating one of the properties of the objects in array.

Output: `John, Doe`

Any elegant way of how to do it without having to loop through the array?

Comment: How do you want this string formatted?

Comment: Btw, the data type of what are you mentioning in your code snippet should be an array of dictionaries (`[[String: String]]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a number of options

```
a.map({$0.name}).description
```

will produce ["John", "Doe"]

```
a.map({$0.name}).joined()
```

will produce JohnDoe

```
a.map({$0.name}).joined(separator:",")
```

will produce John,Doe

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution without loop is `map`ping the array to the `name` values and `join`ing them using a space as separator:

```
let array = [["id":343, "name":"John"], ["id":342, "name":"Doe"]]

let fullName = array.map{$0["name"] as! String}.joined(separator: " ")
```